# How to dynamically allocate proper memory to a variable which causes Segmentation fault, by using Signal handler?

Tags: linux, signals, interrupt-handling

I had been asked a question,  how to allocated memory to a pointer which has just caused a SIGSEVG signal, can we do it by using a signal handler ?

Answer (score 0):

SIGSEGV signal causes the program to terminate. However, what you are asking can be done but I don't see any reason to continue the program execution after a memory violation has occurred.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <malloc.h>
int *p;
void sighandler(int);

int main()
{
    signal(SIGSEGV, sighandler);
    printf("\nProcess %d waits for someone to send it SIGSEGV\n",
        getpid());

    scanf("%d", p);
    printf("%d", *p);
    return 0;
}

void sighandler(int signum)
{
    p = malloc(sizeof(int));
    printf("\n\nProcess %d got signal %d\n\n", getpid(), signum);
    signal(signum, SIG_DFL);
    main();
}
```

However, this still causes SIGSEGV, but prints the entered number from 2nd attempt onwards.